# creating an icon of a shortcut of a batch file using nsis installer

Tags: installation, icons, batch-file, nsis

I need to set an icon for my batch file OR  for the shortcut of my batch file , using the nsis installer. 
Can an icon be set only of a shortcut , or can i set the icon of the main batch file whose shortcut needs to be created.

The following code isn't working:

I have a folder `MyAccountSoftware`,  my installer will compile the files of this folder into the exe file.
This folder has these two files :-

```
---MyAccountSoftware
       |______Account.BAT
       |______Account.ico

  SetOutPath $INSTDIR\  
  File "MyAccountSoftware\Account.BAT"  

CreateShortCut "$INSTDIR\Account.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Account.BAT" "$INSTDIR\Account.ico"
```

This code, just copies the file `Account.BAT` into the required `$INSTDIR`,  and creates a shortcut -
`Account.Ink`  in the `$INSTDIR`, but doesn't set the icon of the Shortcut.
Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Batch files cannot have custom icons. When creating the shortcut, even if you don't need a parameter you still need to provide a empty string:

```
CreateShortCut "$INSTDIR\Account.lnk" "$INSTDIR\Account.BAT" "" "$INSTDIR\Account.ico"
```

Comment: sir, i have a post here, please help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959585/filecopy-of-nsis-installer-not-working-in-windows-7-but-working-in-windows-xp