# FileCopy of NSIS installer not working in Windows 7 but working in Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-xp, nsis, file-copying

I am using FileCopy of NSIS installer to copy a folder along with its all subfiles from a source to destination. This works on XP but not on Windows 7. When i run the installer on Windows 7 , then the FileCopy dialog doesn't even appears, it is just skipped out.
But in Windows XP, it properly shows the dialog box of "Copying Files" and succeeds.
What's the problem? Please help.

```
!define FileCopy `!insertmacro FileCopy`
!macro FileCopy FilePath TargetDir
  CreateDirectory `${TargetDir}`
  CopyFiles `${FilePath}` `${TargetDir}`
!macroend

   ${FileCopy} 'C:\ACCBK\*.*' '$INSTDIR\ACCBK\'
```

Comment: Perhaps it needs Administrator privileges. Did you try launching it with Run As Administrator option?

Comment: how to do it? also, if i don't want to put this validation of Users , then how to remove it?

Comment: Did you try using the UAC plug-in? http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu : how to do it? also, if i don't want to put this validation of Users , then how to remove it?  i mean , any user can run the installer, then what to do??  please help with the code, sir.

Comment: i dont want to use any plugin,  i just want that filecopy works on both Windows 7 as well as on XP, currently its working on XP, but not on 7, even if am logged in via Administrator?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with NSIS, so you will need to do some research. Did you read the article I mentioned? It doesn't matter if you are an Administrator, it matters only if the installation process is running with Administrator privileges or not. Basically, you need to elevate the installer process even if you have enough privileges.

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu: how to launch it with Run As Administrator option? can you tell me the code

Comment: It's an option in Windows which appears when you right-click a file. To do it programmatically for a NSIS installer you need to use something like UAC plug-in. Please note that there are a lot of commercial setup authoring tools which are much easier to use than NSIS.

Comment: can you mention some of them?

Comment: Advanced Installer and InstallShield are my favorites. You can find a bigger list here: http://www.installsite.org/ (under "Windows Installer -> Authoring Tools"). NSIS should also work. I'm not sure why you don't want to try the UAC plug-in.

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu: The UAC plugin is not for elevating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure the installer runs as admin, use this code:

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin ;Require admin rights on NT6+ (When UAC is turned on)

!include LogicLib.nsh

Function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
    Quit
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

If this is the problem, it means it was actually broken on XP as well (Any version of NT really), you just forgot to test as non-admin.

CopyFiles just calls SHFileOperation, but there could be some breaking changes between XP and Vista+ of course...

Comment: @Anders : sir, i want that anybody can run the installer, any user or admin

Comment: also, the code which i have mentioned in the post, i have executed on Windows 7 as an Administrator, then also , the FileCopy operation was failed.

Comment: for anybody to run the installer, what code shall i mention sir? please help

Comment: @sqlchild: Only administrators can write to $windir, $programfiles and HKLM

Comment: @Anders : sir, am not writing to any of these folders? then it should work, but why is not copying files on Windows 7

Comment: @Anders : also, am not using UAC plugin or any else, is any needed?

Comment: @Anders : what help the Process Monitor would provide? am not aware of it

Comment: @Anders: need your help sir ----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013926/read-from-a-file-while-installation-in-nsis-but-do-no-copy-it-on-the-destination